# Sitecore - How do I correctly populate the Item.Fields hashtable with names for the key (not GUIDs)?

Tags: c#, .net, sitecore

This is a bit of a strange one with Sitecore... Basically I'm accessing an item from the Content API but it's not populating the Item.Fields hashtable with keys based on the text for the field (I guess I'd call this a field name) but rather with a GUID.

For example, here is some code I'm using to get an item:

```
var database = global::Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase("master");
var item = database.GetItem("/sitecore/content/Home");
item.Fields.ReadAll();  // edit, per recommendation... does not work
Sitecore.Data.Fields.Field f = item.Fields["SomeText"];
Assert.IsNotNull(f):  // This fails
```

If I set a breakpoint and debug, I can see that there are values (indeed, the correct values) inside the Item.Fields hashtable, but the keys are all based on GUIDs rather than "field names" as most code samples regarding usage of this API suggest.

**EDIT:**  Upon closer inspection, the DisplayName and Name fields are coming back as empty strings from the API (note these are clearly defined in Sitecore so still not sure what the issue is).  It appears these *might* be used in conjunction with GUID as some sort of key for the hashtable.

**Question:**  Is there something I'm doing wrong here?  I've published the data template and the content item.  Clearly the connection is being made because I'm getting results back from the API and even the correct values, just not the keys I'm expecting to use to reference the data values.

References:

- http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore6/content_api_cookbook-a4.pdf - checkout the example right at the top of page 28 where they access the "title" field.  Also, check out the example directly below in 4.1.1 "How to Access System Fields" where they use static helpers with the GUIDs instantiated in a private static constructor.  Is this the preferred method for accessing "user defined" fields?

Screenshot of sample data from Sitecore (notices the GUIDs as keys):

[image]

Code Samples from above linked document:

Accessing the "title" field:

```
Sitecore.Data.Database master = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase("master");
Sitecore.Data.Items.Item home = master.GetItem("/sitecore/content/home");
Sitecore.Data.Fields.Field titleField = home.Fields["title"];
if(titleField!=null)
{
  home.Editing.BeginEdit();
  titleField.Value = "//TODO: replace with appropriate value";
  home.Editing.EndEdit();
}
```

Accessing the system field "ArchiveDate":

```
Sitecore.Data.Database master = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase("master");
Sitecore.Data.Items.Item sample = master.GetItem("/sitecore/content/home/sample");
Sitecore.Data.Fields.DateField archiveField =
sample.Fields[Sitecore.FieldIDs.ArchiveDate];
```

Decompiling the Sitecore.Kernel.dll we can see that:

```
public static class FieldIDs
{
    // stripped down version

    /// <summary>The ID of the 'Archive date' field.</summary>
    public static ID ArchiveDate;

    static FieldIDs()
    {
        FieldIDs.ArchiveDate = new ID("{56C15C6D-FD5A-40CA-BB37-64CEEC6A9BD5}");
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess the main question is whether you are attempting to access system fields or other types of fields.  System fields are referenced by GUID.  Could you identify what `SomeText` is in your code?

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I'm definitely trying to access "other types of fields" not the system fields.  As an example, imagine SomeText is a paragraph of text (string) that CMS users (aka non-technical users) could update in the CMS and have those changes reflected on say the home page of their web site.

Comment: so on the item.Fields collection, the Name property on the Field items is an empty string?

Comment: @techphoria414 Yes, the Name, DisplayName, and Type fields are all empty strings.  Tried the new ID("{56C15C6D-FD5A-40CA-BB37-64CEEC6A9BD5}") method and that actually worked which means I'd need to embed all the GUIDs for the data template fields in the code.

Comment: Technically that's the better practice anyway. We typically keep a structure of constants for Field IDs. Or you can codegen it with TDS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I ended up going the route I mentioned in the question (which is what Sitecore uses internally and, @technophoria414 mentioned, a Sitecore developer best practice).

Basically:

```
namespace MyProject.Core.Data.Sitecore.Fields
{
    public static class ContentItem
    {
        // stripped down version

        public static ID DESCRIPTION_TEXT;

        static ContentItem()
        {
            DESCRIPTION_TEXT= new ID("{56C15C6D-FD5A-40CA-BB37-64CEEC6A9BD5}");  // this will be some GUID out of Sitecore 
        }
    }
}
```

Usage would be something like this:

```
var query = string.Format("fast:/sitecore/content/HomePageItems//*[@ContentSlug='{0}']", input);
var item = Database.SelectSingleItem(query);
var descriptionText = item.Fields[ContentItem.DESCRIPTION_TEXT].Value;
```

Answer (score 4):

If I understand correctly, you want the Fields collection to return **all** the fields available for that item, even if they do not have a value. By default, Sitecore will only return those fields that have a value.

You can solve this by calling the `ReadAll()` method before accessing the fields collection.
So in your example:

```
item.Fields.ReadAll();
Sitecore.Data.Fields.Field f = item.Fields["SomeText"];
Assert.IsNotNull(f):  // This succeeds
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Someone else recommended it as well, and it does seem to fix a lot of similar issues so it's definitely a good trick to have in your tool box, but it didn't work in my case.  I definitely am getting the fields, they just don't have names so I really have no context as to which field is which (because the keys are GUIDs).

Answer (score 3):

I had a problem with identical symptoms. The root cause for me was a publishing issue. The folder containing my template was not published, though the template itself was. So I could see the fields in the debugger with the correct values and ids, but not the names. The solution was to ensure that all the parents of my template were also published.